# How to access files on Google Colab notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How can I access the files on the left bar of Google Colab? By default sample data is given, when I run `!ls sample_data` command it lists the files as it should:

```
anscombe.json             mnist_test.csv
california_housing_test.csv   mnist_train_small.csv
california_housing_train.csv  README.md
```

But when I run following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv')
print(data.head())
```

I get an error: FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using upload will place the files under / if you dont move them, so try /PetImages/Dogs/, alternatively you can upload them to google drive and mount your google drive giving access to your files in colab running this in a cell

```
from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

copy over the folder to /content/ using 
`!cp  /content/drive/My\ Drive/PetImages.zip /content/`
then use `!unzip PetImages.zip`

now your directory will be /content/PetImages/Dogs/ which might be easier as uploading directory to colab is slower and gets deleted after 12 hours.

Comment: Unfortunately I still cannot get it to work, I have updated my problem description

Comment: have you tried doing '/content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv' notice the / at the beginning on content

Answer (score 1):

July 2020

I see you just missing / before dir

```
import pandas as pd
#data = pd.read_csv('content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv')
# this is corrct one
data = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv')
print(data.head())
```

[image: see colab output]

Answer (score 1):

The directory is not in G-Drive, it is VM of colab. 
So the `'sample_data/'` directory path is `'./sample_data/'`
You should change the path, then O.K.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('./sample_data/mnist_test.csv')
print(data.head())
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to list those files with the command **!ls** ? Have you already mounted your google drive to colab to access those files? if not, please do so by following the commands mentioned [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@uditsaini/access-google-drive-and-mount-google-drive-to-colab-notebook-google-ccbca1691d31)

Comment: Yes, I can access them, I just dont know how to access them through code. Similarly to how you would access a file on desktop by writing path = "C:\Desktop\Filename.txt"

Comment: This code should work 

import os
import glob
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'PetImages/Dogs/')
for file in glob.glob(path+'*.jpg'):  #Assuming jpg format
  img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  print(np.array(img))
  plt.imshow(img)