# How to save json dumps in google colab using python?

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

x = json.dumps (....)

how to save x to a json file and store it in google drive or download it to local pc using google colab

currently using this when i am in local pc

```
 with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951120/how-to-access-files-on-google-colab-notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading it to your local drive, [reference here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=hauvGV4hV-Mh&uniqifier=1)

```
from google.colab import files
import json

x = json.dumps ('test')
y = x.encode('utf-8')
with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(str(y))

files.download('example.txt')
```

Alternatively, I as previously mentioned in the comment, you can mount your Google drive using the script provided or simply click the mount drive then run the cell provided. After mounting, you can now write to it like a local drive, [fyr](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=c2W5A2px3doP&uniqifier=1).

[image: Mount Google Drive]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Christopher, you can take help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951120/how-to-access-files-on-google-colab-notebook). The link will help you to eventually mount Google Colab as a local drive. Once this is done, you can easily read-write the file from/to Google Colab.
In my opinion, it's worth trying and it should work.
Note : I've not tried and tested this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# open existing text file
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Sandbox/Sandbox.txt’) as f:
  print(f.read())

# make new JSON file
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Sandbox/Sandbox_2.json', 'w') as f:
  f.write('{"hello":true}')
```

From [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/865).