# How do I use the dataset of ".mat" type in google colab on a Mac?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to use the dataset named "data.mat" on my google colab on my MacBook.

Here is the code for wanting to use the dataset values:

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = scipy.io.loadmat('data.mat')
train_X = data['X'].T
train_y = data['y'].T
test_X = data['Xval'].T
test_y = data['yval'].T
```

I tried uploading the document onto drive, but even after doing so I am unable to access it on my colab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access files on Google Colab notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951120/how-to-access-files-on-google-colab-notebook)

Comment: You need to be more clear than "I am unable to".

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on how the .mat file is set up. Meaning, if you saved a struct to a .mat file and called it "Data" and the file is data.mat, I recommend as you already started:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd

path = '...'
raw_data = loadmat(f'{path}/data.mat', squeeze_me=True)
data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data['Data'])
```

Hope that helps.